# Combine Scripts Handler error 500

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I use ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager to manage my script and controlBundles to reduce js ajax size. It work well on my development machine but on my production server i have an error 500 when CombineScriptsHandler.axd is called.

I try adding axd Mine type, change my dev to https like in prod but with no result. I have no error message in the windows event viewer. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it work now using application pool in integrate mode. I remove httpHandler from my web.config to change from classic.